# C# A buffer overrun has occurred

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

```
A buffer overrun has occurred in MyApp.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state.
```

I've tried a few things but can't figure out what's causing the above in 1/50 calls, probably something obvious, it's a lot to guess at.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out UInt32 pid);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

public static IntPtr GetProcessWindow(int processId)
{
    UInt32 pid = 0;
    UInt32 dwThreadId = 0;
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    IntPtr hwnd = GetTopWindow(IntPtr.Zero);

    while(hwnd != null)
    {
        dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        GetWindowText(hwnd, a, 256);
        String name = a.ToString();
        if(pid == processId && name.Contains("[Window Name]"))
            return hwnd;
        hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, 2);
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the error? ie. Which line? What's the stack trace?

Comment: To anybody reading this post: this is very unlikely to be your problem when you found this by googling the error message.  The bug causes heap corruption but the error message is almost always a stack corruption problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not pre-allocating the buffer in the `StringBuilder`.

This line:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
```

Should be:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(256);
```

Comment: +1 It's clearly explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx): *The only caveat is that the `StringBuilder` must be allocated enough space for the return value, or the text will overflow, causing an exception to be thrown by P/Invoke.* Meaning that OP's code should only work if the text is smaller than the default `StringBuilder` capacity (which is implementation specific, but currently 16 in .NET 4.5 IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing `StringBuilder` with a capacity defined by the `GetWindowTextLength` API call.